# Converting DataFrame containing UTF-8 and Nulls to String Without Losing Data

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my code for reading in this dataframe:

```
html = 'https://www.agroindustria.gob.ar/sitio/areas/ss_mercados_agropecuarios/logistica/_archivos/000023_Posici%C3%B3n%20de%20Camiones%20y%20Vagones/000010_Entrada%20de%20camiones%20y%20vagones%20a%20puertos%20semanal%20y%20mensual.php'
url = urlopen(html)
df = pd.read_html(html, encoding = 'utf-8')
remove = []

for x in range(len(df)):
    if len(df[x]) < 10:
        remove.append(x)

for x in remove[::-1]:
    df.pop(x)

df = df[0]
```

The dataframe contained uses both ',' and '.' as thousands indicators, and i want neither. So 5.103 should be 5103.

Using this code:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.', ''))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))
```

All of the data will get changed, but the values in the last four columns will all turn to NaN. I'm assuming this has something to do with trying to use str.replace on a float?

Trying any sort of df[column] = df[column].astype(str) also gives back errors, as does something convoluted like the following:

```
for x in df.columns.tolist():
    for k, v in df[x].iteritems():
        if pd.isnull(v) == False and type(v) = float:
            df.loc(k, df[x]) == str(v)
```

What is the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex approach. I haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d+)[.,](\d+)',r'\1\2',str(x)))
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to break the dataframe